# Regular expression - Phone number ( including +, (,), and length validation - C#

Tags: c#, regex, phone-number

Recently I've to come up with a regular expression for phone number , so as this is already done by many of the devs , i've found a solution related to the same.
And made use of the same in production.

**Version#1** is only with numbers:

```
@"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}"
```

But then there is an additional requirement: we need to allow special characters like `-` and `(` `)`
So I modified the regular expression to **Version#2** as mentioned below:

```
@"^([\+]?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2})[\s-]?[\(]?(0?[0-9]\d{0,4}[\)]?[-\s]?)([0-9][\d-\s]{5,7}[\s]?)(x[\d-]{0,4})?$"
```

Now while validating length of the phone number QA found out that it's accepting more than 16 characters , I've to work again on the regular expression to make it work.

This is where I've found the problem related to Length of the phone number validation using regular expression.

- **Is there any way to indicate that phone number should accept minimum length as 10 and maximum length as 15 by modifying regular expression ?**

*Example here could be `123456789` - want to mark this as Invalid phone number as it's having only **9** digits*
*Example here could be `1234567890123456` - want to mark this as Invalid phone number as it's having only **16** digits*

- **Is there any way to indicate single left parenthesis and single right parenthesis is Invalid inside phone number by modifying regular expression ?**

*Example here could be `12(34567890` - want to mark this as Invalid phone number , as it's having **left parenthesis** only*

Currently I achieved above things by adding custom attributes to the phone number field. I really want to know , if there's way where we can achieve above things by modifying regular expression itself ?

Comment: You could use an alternation, one which matches a number in parentheses and the other which matches a number without them.

Comment: Are you trying to allow 10 to 15 digits only ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/6DlhE2/1))? Or the overall string length can be 10 to 15 chars ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvoL7K/1))?

Comment: Could you please post some more testing data? (I don't know much about different phone number formats)

Comment: Why do you even try to make a difficult Regex for this? I mean.. if you dail any Number in any Phone, you wont type in the special Characters, except the Plus probably. I would simply filter everything out, that is not a Number and format it afterwards.

Comment: If you change the *Version#2* to `^(\+?\d{1,3})[\s-]?\(?(0?\d{1,5}\)?[-\s]?)(\d[\d-\s]{5,7}\s?)(x[\d-]{0,4})?$` it's easier to read (and it'll fit on a row). It has exactly the same meaning as yours, just removed and contracted some things.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please post me regular expression which will help me do that. Thanks.

Comment: @VenkataramanaMadugula Well what I had in mind was something like `\(\d{9}\)|\d{9}` ... this would match either 9 digits with no parentheses or 9 digits with parentheses balanced.  Unbalanced parentheses would not match.  Of course your actual expression is more complicated than this, but this is a suggestion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to allow 10 t0 15 digits only. Looks like you've cracked it as i've added more tests and see. would you mind explaining the logic , how you cracked it ?

Comment: @BrightOne - Here goes the complete set of data                                                                                 Positive Test Cases:+9-123-4567890
+9-123-456-7890
+9(123)4567890
123456789012345
02 5555555 x4545
+1 (212) 7777777
+1-(800)-555-2468
+44 7777 777-777
+44 20 44444444
+91 9999999999
+919000075855
+1 (425) 406-6477
+1 (212) 777 7777                                                                           
 Negative Test Cases: +1 (234) abc ab58
+1 )234( 7777777
+91 /*caf asf+1
+1 1235
abcd

Comment: Ok, I will post now with explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex with a `(?=(?:\D*\d){10,15}\D*$)` positive lookahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){10,15}\D*$)\+?[0-9]{1,3}[\s-]?(?:\(0?[0-9]{1,5}\)|[0-9]{1,5})[-\s]?[0-9][\d\s-]{5,7}\s?(?:x[\d-]{0,4})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6DlhE2/3).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){10,15}\D*$)` - **a positive lookahead that makes sure there are 10 to 15 sequences of non-digits followed with 1 digit, and then has 0+ digits up to the end of string**
- `\+?` - an optional `+` symbol
- `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `[\s-]?` - an optional whitespace or `-`
- `(?:\(0?[0-9]{1,5}\)|[0-9]{1,5})` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\(0?[0-9]{1,5}\)` - a `(`,  1 to 5 digits, `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]{1,5}` - 1 to 5 digits
- `[-\s]?` - an optional whitespace or `-`
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[\d\s-]{5,7}` - 5 to 7 digits, whitespaces or `-`
- `\s?`  - an optional whitespace
- `(?:x[\d-]{0,4})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `x` - a literal `x`
  - `[\d-]{0,4}` - 0 to 4 digits of `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: (?=(?:\D*\d){10,15}\D*$) - a positive lookahead that makes sure there are 10 to 15 sequences of digits right ? not non-digits isn't it ?

Comment: @VenkataramanaMadugula; I have written what it means. `\D*` matches zero or more non-digits (to allow the spaces, hyphens, etc. what your *consuming* pattern - the one that is not inside a lookahead - matches) and `\d` matches a digit. Once grouped and quantified as `(?:\D*\d){10,15}`, the whole `\D*\d` is repeated 10 to 15 times: `\D*\d(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)(?:\D*\d)?(?:\D*\d)?(?:\D*\d)?(?:\D*\d)?(?:\D*\d)?`.

Comment: The lookahead requires 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 or 15 digits, no more, no less in the string. If the condition is not met, the engine won't even try to match the string with  the rest of the pattern.